# Unable to capture or show the compare_model() metrics in streamlit

Tags: python-3.x, streamlit, pycaret

I have created streamlit app to allow me to run multiple experiments on a dataset using PyCaret Time series. My problem is that I am unable to capture and show the compare_model() results table in my streamlit app, (the metrics table that shows the performance in all tested algorithms).

Here is my code:

```
    import streamlit as st
    from pycaret.time_series import TSForecastingExperiment
    from pycaret.time_series import *

    # set up for time series forecasting
    exp_auto = TSForecastingExperiment()
    exp_auto.setup(
        data=df_exog, target='qty', fh=fh, enforce_exogenous=False,
        numeric_imputation_target="ffill", numeric_imputation_exogenous="ffill",
        scale_target="minmax",
        scale_exogenous="minmax",
        fold_strategy="expanding",
        session_id=42,verbose=False)
    
    
    
    if st.button("Run Time series models:"):
    
        best = exp_auto.compare_models(sort="mape", turbo=False,verbose=True)
        st.write(best)
```

I can not get the metrics table to print out, i keep getting the setup table results instead of the compare_model() results, although I tried verbose=False in the setup()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default `compare_models()` didn't return results as DataFrame instead it returned the **trained model**. If you want the metrics table try to use `pull()` to get the last printed score grid and then you can display it on streamlit.

```py
from pycaret.datasets import get_data
from pycaret.time_series import TSForecastingExperiment
import streamlit as st

# Get data
y = get_data('airline', verbose=False)

# Experiment
exp = TSForecastingExperiment()
exp.setup(data=y, fh=12, verbose=False)

if st.button("Run Time series models:"):
    best = exp.compare_models(include=['arima','exp_smooth','ets'], verbose=False)
    # Pull metrics
    metrics = exp.pull()
    st.write(metrics)
    
    # Plot graph
    exp.plot_model(estimator=best, display_format='streamlit')
```

[image: demo]